# Mockito ClassCastException

Tags: java, testing, mocking, mockito

The method I want to test has a for loop with logic for each element in bList:

```
class A {
    void someMethod(){

        for(B b: bList){
            //some logic for b
        }
    }
}
```

I get an exception when executing following test:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
class ATest {

    @Mock
    private B b;

    @Mock
    private Map<Int, List<B>> bMap;

    @Mock(answer = Answers.RETURNS_DEEP_STUBS)
    private List<B> bList;

    @Spy
    @InjectMocks
    private C c;
    ....

    @Test
    public void test(){

        //this line executes fine
        when(bList.size()).thenReturn(1);

        //strangely this works fine
        when(bMap.get(any())).thenReturn(bList);

        //ClassCastException
        when(bList.get(0)).thenReturn(b); // or when(bList.get(anyInt())).thenReturn(b);

        c.methodIWantToTest();
    }
}
```

The exception I get is:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException:
org.mockito.internal.creation.jmock.ClassImposterizer$ClassWithSuperclassToWorkAroundCglibBug$$EnhancerByMockitoWithCGLIB$$ cannot be cast to xyz.B
```

Has anyone encountered this before and come up with a workaround?

I have searched for a solution and have come across some links: 
http://code.google.com/p/mockito/issues/detail?id=251
 and
http://code.google.com/p/mockito/issues/detail?id=107

Comment: It may be an existing issue as pointed out in the links.

Comment: Are you really trying to mock List and Map or is that just to illustrate the issue? Why don't you just use an ArrayList and HashMap implementation and inject those?

Comment: @jhericks Yes you are correct, I should switch to using ArrayList and HashMap implementation. Thanks

Answer (score 20, accepted):

As [this link you posted](http://code.google.com/p/mockito/issues/detail?id=251) indicates, you've encountered a bug with `Answers.RETURNS_DEEP_STUBS`.

I don't actually see any reason to actually use `RETURNS_DEEP_STUBS` in your example code.  You really should try to evaluate whether or not you need deep stubs, because, as the [Mockito docs say](http://mockito.googlecode.com/svn/tags/1.8.3/javadoc/org/mockito/Mockito.html#RETURNS_DEEP_STUBS), "every time a mock returns a mock a fairy dies."  So if you can,  just take that out and your example will work.

However, if you insist on using deep stubs, you can hack around this error by up-casting the return value from the method call to `Object`.  For example, replace the offending line in your code with this:

```
when((Object)bList.get(0)).thenReturn(b);
```

All that being said, I personally agree with @jhericks.  The best solution is probably to use an actual `ArrayList` which contains your mock as opposed to mocking `List`.  The only problem is getting your list injected, so you'd have to use `@Spy`.  For example:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
class ATest{
  private B b = mock(B.class);
  @Spy
  private List<B> bList = new ArrayList<B>() {{ add(b); }};

  @InjectMocks
  private C c = new C();

  @Test
  public void test(){
    c.methodIWantToTest();
    // verify results
  }
}
```

Comment: I tried both the alternatives and they both work. I see the case as stated in the Mockito docs and will refrain from using mocks to return mocks. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately this is not possible

Case: tests on API:

```
interface ConfigurationBuilder {...}
configurationBuilder.newServerAction("s1").withName("111")....create();
```

Main reason of this usage is compatibility maintenance on compile time.
But mockito cannot support generics in chains with RETURNS_MOCKS and RETURNS_DEEP_STUBS options due to type erasure in java:

```
Builder/*<ServerActionBuilder>-erasured generic*/ b = configurationBuilder.newServerAction("s1");
b.withName("111")...create();
```

Result in example above should be ServerAction but in mockito it is Object of generated class.

see [Issue: Can not Return deep stubs from generic method that returns generic type #484](https://github.com/mockito/mockito/issues/484)